# Windows 7, repetition of audio tick.wav, like those Unix guys can do, from other application.

Tags: windows-7, audio, unix, emacs, cygwin

At [org-pomodoro_resources at master · lolownia_org-pomodoro · GitHub / resources](https://github.com/lolownia/org-pomodoro/tree/master/resources), there is a `tick.wav` file, to be played repetitively, from Emacs.

I have tried `start`, `wmplayer`, `vlc`, `play` (`sox`), and `mpc-hc64`.

None of them seem to behave like what those Unix folks have. The `mpc-h64` came closest, though it had also opened up a GUI instance, and the ticks weren't well spaced and consistent, as there seemed to be a delay after Emacs is sending these "signals". (Actually, I never got `play` to work, perhaps because I am not `cygwin` proficient.)

If you feel the impulse to try this out, here are my Emacs lines of code:

```
(setq org-pomodoro-play-ticking-sounds t)
;; (setq org-pomodoro-audio-player (or (executable-find "aplay") 
;;                                     (executable-find "afplay")
;;                                     ))
(setq org-pomodoro-audio-player "c:/Program Files/MPC-HC/mpc-hc64.exe")
```

Is there a better way? That is, perfect world is smooth ticking sound emitted, with hopefully no GUI popping up (`vlc` generated so many!). Can Windows allow such signal from Emacs to an audio player?